# How to apply impulse to a body to make it fly away?

Tags: box2d, jbox2d

I'm playing around with jbox2d and can't really make a body "fly away" as if from an explosion.

From what I have found on the net, making the body fly away from the world center (0,0), should have been something like that:

```
b.applyLinearImpulse( new Vec2(0,0) , b.getPosition() );
```

But really it just doesn't do anything, any idea why? Also how do I change the strength of the impulse, like if it want to make it fly skyhigh or just move a bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument of applyLinearImpulse is the vector which is the strength of the force/impulse. So just change it to something else rather than 0,0 and your object should fly.

Comment: yes! :) changed it to (0,5000) and now they fly upwards. :) thanks!